# How to extract the column with only False condition without apply

Tags: pandas

```
df[['uid','verified','is_duplicate']].head(2)
```

How to get only where `is_duplicate=False`

```
    uid    verified is_duplicate
0   2355954 True    True
1   2626002 True    False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a mask:

```
df = df[['uid','verified','is_duplicate']].head(2)
df = [~df.is_duplicate]
```

Comment: can i apply on this data frame ? df[['uid','verified','is_duplicate']].head(2)

Answer (score 1):

Since the values are already booleans, you can just negate the condition:

```
df[~df.is_duplicate]
```

Which gives:

```
       uid  verified  is_duplicate
1  2626002      True         False
```

Comment: do i need to create a new dataframe for this or can i apply on this data frame ? df[['uid','verified','is_duplicate']].head(2)

Comment: The expression results in a data frame, so you can `df1 = df[~df.is_duplicate]` then `df1[['uid','verified','is_duplicate']].head(2)`